# .NET get DeviceId from Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client.ModuleClient

Tags: azure-iot-sdk

I would like to get the assigned device-id from [Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client.ModuleClient](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-csharp/blob/master/iothub/device/src/ModuleClient.cs) assigned from the IoT-Hub to my module.

What is the best way to retrieve the device-id at runtime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So we have to make use of a back-end solution to Read Module Twin Properties, like deviceId.
This is by design, you have to make use of Back end app as stated in following Document : [Module twins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-module-twins#module-twins) , Inside the Module App only Desired and Reported are available.
[image]

Please refer to [Get started with IoT Hub module identity and module twin (.NET)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-csharp-csharp-module-twin-getstarted)

**Sample Console C# app :** Make use of 'registryManager' to query all devices with the [query language](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-query-language#c-example). The query functionality is exposed by the [C# service SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-sdks) in the RegistryManager class.

> var query = registryManager.CreateQuery("SELECT * FROM devices", 100);

Complete sample console C# code snippet is as shown below. [using Microsoft.Azure.Devices;]

```
using Microsoft.Azure.Devices;
using Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Common.Exceptions;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CreateIds
{
    class Program
    {
        const string connectionString ="<>";     
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            GetDeviceIdAsync().Wait();
        }
        private static async Task GetDeviceIdAsync()
        {
            RegistryManager registryManager =
              RegistryManager.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString);
            try
            {
                
                var query = registryManager.CreateQuery("SELECT * FROM devices", 100);
                while (query.HasMoreResults)
                {
                    var page = await query.GetNextAsTwinAsync();
                    foreach (var twin in page)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(twin.DeviceId));
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (DeviceAlreadyExistsException dvcEx)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error : {0}", dvcEx);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Update 1:
Using 'Where' clause to get deviceId
Example json twin from **devices.modules** looks like the below one. Now we have to query by using 'Where' clause like moduleId='sampleModule'

```
Sample:{"deviceId":"devkitdps","moduleId":"sampleModule","etag":"AAAAAAAAAAE=","version":4,"status":"enabled","statusUpdateTime":"0001-01-01T00:00:00Z","connectionState":"Disconnected","lastActivityTime":"0001-01-01T00:00:00Z","cloudToDeviceMessageCount":0,"authenticationType":"sas","x509Thumbprint":{"primaryThumbprint":null,"secondaryThumbprint":null},"properties":{"desired":{"$metadata":{"$lastUpdated":"0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"},"$version":1},"reported":{"DateTimeLastAppLaunch":"2020-06-23T17:22:19.4938255-07:00","$metadata":{"$lastUpdated":"2020-06-24T00:22:19.6523448Z","DateTimeLastAppLaunch":{"$lastUpdated":"2020-06-24T00:22:19.6523448Z"}},"$version":3}}}

  var query = registryManager.CreateQuery("SELECT * FROM devices.modules Where moduleId='sampleModule'", 100);
                while (query.HasMoreResults)
                {
                    var page = await query.GetNextAsTwinAsync();
                    foreach (var twin in page)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(twin.DeviceId));
                    }
                }
```

Please let us know if you need further help!

Comment: Thanks for the detailed description, but I would like to know my device ID in my module, not querying all device id's.

Comment: @StefanWalter, Please use the query language to filter the result json something like -->  "SELECT * FROM devices.modules Where moduleId='sampleModule'" and finally we can use the twin.DeviceId property to read from. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: @SathishBoddu-MSFT I think we are talking two different things. I don't want to query from all devices. I have developed an Edge Module and I would like to know the Device-ID which is assigned to the module/device at runtime. That means I want to know my own device ID from a ModuleClient instance.